# can't center a text with text-align: center in angular material application

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am developping an angular material application. One component has the following html template (app.component.html)

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <div class="md-toolbar-tools" style="display: inline-block">
    Liste des annonces
    <span flex></span>
  </div>
</mat-toolbar>>
..........
..........
```

In app.component.css, I tried to apply these styles

```
mat-card {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 2em auto;
  text-align: center;
}

mat-toolbar div {
    text-align: center;
}
.md-toolbar-tools {
    text-align: center;
}

mat-toolbar-row {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

But, the text "Liste des annonces" is not centered. Can you give me a help ?

Comment: Do you want it to be vertically centered

Comment: Please provide the image of the actual results and wanted result of the centre so the problem can be understood

Comment: Use Chrome's debbugger to see how boxes are sized. If the div has the same width than the text inside it, the `text-align` property won't do anything, since you should center the div itself, and not its content...

Comment: Random's suggestion was right. I put the following

Comment: <mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <div style="width:100%;" class="md-toolbar-tools" >
    Liste des annonces
    <span flex></span>
  </div>
</mat-toolbar>